# Jquery change event not triggring

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net

this is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>DDL change </title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            BindState();
            doit();
            $('#ddlState').on('change', function () {  //this method is not triggering..
                $('.ddlCity').val(parseInt(4)).change();
            });
        });
        function BindCity() {
            $('.ddlCity').append('<option value="1">one</option><option value="2">Two</option><option value="3">Three</option><option value="4">Four</option><option value="5">Five</option>');
        };
        function BindState() {
            $('#ddlState').append('<option value="1">one</option><option value="2">Two</option><option value="3">Three</option><option value="4">Four</option><option value="5">Five</option>');
        };
        function doit() {
            $('#ddlState').val(parseInt(3)).change();
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <select id="ddlState" onchange="BindCity()">
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <select class="ddlCity"></select>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

on change event is not triggering dynamically ,if i change drop down manually event will fire..
kindly explain  me  what is the problem

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `change()` does not fire an event, it subscribes to one.

You are looking for [`jQuery#trigger`](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/):

However, in this case I would suggest just moving the logic to another function, which you can call at any time. I have named it `adjustCity` but I'm sure you can come up with a better description for it.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>DDL change </title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        function adjustCity () {
            $('.ddlCity').val(4)
        }
        $(document).ready(function () {
            BindState();
            $('#ddlState').on('change', adjustCity);
            doit();
        });
        function BindCity() {
            $('.ddlCity').append('<option value="1">one</option><option value="2">Two</option><option value="3">Three</option><option value="4">Four</option><option value="5">Five</option>');
        };
        function BindState() {
            $('#ddlState').append('<option value="1">one</option><option value="2">Two</option><option value="3">Three</option><option value="4">Four</option><option value="5">Five</option>');
        };
        function doit() {
            $('#ddlState').val(3).trigger('change')
            adjustCity()
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <select id="ddlState" onchange="BindCity()">
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <select class="ddlCity"></select>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit: Credit to [AHBagheri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1470305/ahbagheri) for reminding me to move the `doit()` call.